# Create new column in a DataFrame using values from a different row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe that is the score for the the same id in the next year. See the sample original data below:

```py
Year  ID    Score
2018  785   8.4 
2018  770   -1.2
2017  733   3.2
2017  785   7.9
2018  733   3.9
```

If there is not data for the next year it should fill with an NA. So the output I'm looking for would be:

```py
Year  ID    Score col
2018  785   8.4   NA
2018  770   -1.2  NA
2017  733   3.2   3.9
2017  785   7.9   8.4
2018  733   3.9   NA
```

The data is not currently ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data has consecutive years for all ID's (no ID with `2016 2018`), then you can do:

```
 df['col'] = df.sort_values('Year').groupby('ID').Score.shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
   Year   ID  Score  col
0  2018  785    8.4  NaN
1  2018  770   -1.2  NaN
2  2017  733    3.2  3.9
3  2017  785    7.9  8.4
4  2018  733    3.9  NaN
```

If years are not guaranteed to be consecutive, then do a merge:

```
df.merge(df.assign(Year=lambda x: x.Year - 1),
         on=['Year', 'ID'],
         suffixes = ['','_new'],
         how='left')
```

Output:

```
   Year   ID  Score  Score_new
0  2018  785    8.4        NaN
1  2018  770   -1.2        NaN
2  2017  733    3.2        3.9
3  2017  785    7.9        8.4
4  2018  733    3.9        NaN
```

Comment: Awesome! And if there is a gap in years will it just be an NaN?

Comment: The first solution won't work, it doesn't care about year. See the update