# Generate a new column in pandas DataFrame that contains data from a DIFFERENT row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe with about 200 rows containing data from peer reviews. A sample dataframe looks like this, where reviewer is the "name" of the student reviewing the reviewee.

```
data = {'reviewer': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
        'reviewee':['G','G','H','H','I','I'],
        'reviewer score of reviewee':[1,2,0,0,1,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image: image of output]

Each student is reviewed by two people, so student G is reviewed by student A and B, and so on. I need to score each reviewer based on how well their score aligned with the other reviewer's score (e.g., A and B will be given a low "peer review quality" score because they did not provide the same scores when they reviewed student G). It seems like the best way to accomplish this is to start by generating a new column called "other reviewer score of reviewee." In this first row where student A reviews student G, there would now be a new column with a value of 1 indicating that the other student who reviewed student G gave student G a 1. I would expect the new data frame to look like this:

```
data2 = {'reviewer': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
         'reviewee':['G','G','H','H','I','I'],
         'reviewer score of reviewee':[1,2,0,0,1,2],
         'other reviewer score of reviewee': [2,1,0,0,2,1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

[image: image of output]

There are a handful of other columns in my dataframe not included here - I just want those to remain unchanged which is why I didn't add them into this example dataframe. I understand there are plenty of ways to generate a new column by applying a function to the same row of a data frame, but I haven't been able to figure out how to call upon information in another row.

I looked into options like pivot but those didn't seem to be quite what I need. I did see another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440420/create-new-column-in-a-dataframe-using-values-from-a-different-row) quite similar to this, but I'm struggling to understand the answer provided and map it onto my situation which is different.

Comment: A `pivot` wouldn't give you the shown output but seems like a much more efficient tool to compute reviewer's scores. I believe you should compute the score directly. Do you always have only two reviewer's? If more how do you compute the score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to reverse the order of scores based on "reviewee". You can use `.groupby()` for that:

```py
df["other reviewer score of reviewee"] = df.groupby("reviewee")[
    "reviewer score of reviewee"
].transform(lambda x: x.values[::-1])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  reviewer reviewee  reviewer score of reviewee  other reviewer score of reviewee
0        A        G                           1                                 2
1        B        G                           2                                 1
2        C        H                           0                                 0
3        D        H                           0                                 0
4        E        I                           1                                 2
5        F        I                           2                                 1
```